# GWT: how to change celltable alternate row background colors

Tags: gwt

[image]I am trying to change my celltable alternate rows background colors. 
by default they have white and lite blue color .. is there a possibility i can change these colors to lets say white and red..

attached is the screenshot .. you can see a white and blue color rows .. if there is a solution to change these colors.

I am aboe to change color , but it looks like it is changin each cell color and not the complete background , see the attached image , any way i can avoid these white spaces.

this is my css

```
                  .cellTableEvenRow {
                      }
                .cellTableOddRow {
                 background: powderblue !important;
                   }




               .cellTableEvenRowCell {
                }



                .cellTableOddRowCell {

                  }
```

thanks 
[image]

Answer (score 4):

You have to provide a custom CellTable.Resources instance.
To do that you have to create sub-interfaces of CellTable.Resources and CellTable.Style. In the your custom CellTable.Resources you can add your own CSS file in addition to the default style:

```
public interface CustomResources extends CellTable.Resources {
    @Source({Style.DEFAULT_CSS, "CustomCellTable.css"})
    Style cellTableStyle();
}
public interface CustomStyle extends CellTable.Style {
}
```

Now you can specify your custom style in the CustomCellTable.css:

```
.cellTableEvenRow {
    background: white;
}
.cellTableOddRow {
    background: red;
}
```

To create an instance of your custom CellTable.Resources simply call:

```
CellTable.Resources res = GWT.create(CustomResources.class)
```

Now you can give that instance to the CellTable instance using its constructor:

```
CellTable cellTable=new CellTable(15, res);
```

15 is the default page but can be changed. CellTable has no constructor with only the resources as parameter. At least the page size has to be specified.

Comment: I agree with this answer. This is the correct way of doing it.

Comment: thanks .. this thing works .. But there is a strange problem   i am trying this css ::  .cellTableEvenRow {
   color: red;
    background-color: green;
}
.cellTableOddRow {
    background-color: red;
}                              After this my even rows text color is red , which is fine .. bu there is no effect on background color ... i tried background:green;  and backgorund-color:green as well , but no luck

Comment: If the DEFAULT_CSS is the first one and your custom style is second, it should work correctly.
You can do two things:
1. As ugly but quick solution add "!important" to your css rule -> background-color: green !important;
2. Check what's going on using the dev tools of your browser. There you see if another conflicting css rule breaks your styling and try to fix it.

Comment: thanks .. i have  a progress , but there is a small problem now .. if you can please have a look on my updated question

Comment: I bet, these are the borders of your tds. Use the developer tools to check that, this is what they are for. If the white spaces are boders, then try to set the border-color to the same color as the background: .cellTableOddRow>td {border-color: powderblue; } If necessary, try !important as before.